# Laravel 5.1 creating model overrides per client

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, so I have a Laravel 5.1 project with close to 200 models. This is fine for the core operation of the app, however, in many cases a client may want us to grab something from the database in a special way.

For example, we have a client that wants to calculate the a pension amount slightly different than the normal way.

Is there a design or architecture pattern out there that would allow me to easily switch between client specific model overrides? For example if I am working with "client A" all I do is change a config and it pulls in that clients extensions if they exist but uses the base models if not.

Comment: So basically, you're trying to create a plugin system. But what precisely is your question? This site deals in questions and answers, not in hints. Also, implementation advice is off topic – as the [help/on-topic] explains, this site is only about *software engineering concepts*. Could you please [edit] your question to better explain the design level question you are asking?

Comment: I took out some of the "fluff" and tried to make my question more specific. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, we have a client that wants to calculate the a pension
>   amount slightly different than the normal way.

Implement all client-specific calculations on all models as implementations of the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This way you will be able to quickly swap them.

Comment: I gave you a +1 because I used your answer to start going down a path. Ill mark it as an answer if I end up using it :)

Comment: The thing is I am not sure how I would use the strategy pattern in conjunction with laravel models...although I can see how I could use it to make calculations within the models easily swappable....

Comment: @BillGarrison Well, Strategy implementation is a separate class with only algorithm implementation. Your Strategy can have one method `calculate(MyModel $model)` (you should have abstract class at the top of the hierarchy with this abstract method defined).

Comment: That's an amazing idea...I'm going to mark yours as the answer and try and implement. Thanks!!

Comment: @BillGarrison You are welcome. I'm trying to stay active in `design` and `architecture` tags here and on StackOverflow. So, you are welcome to ask questions ;)